# keep ng-repeat when changing view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat in my `user.html` code and when I click a button in this view, I want to render other html by an `href` that redirect to a new route.

The thing is, I want to keep the ng-repeat that were at `user.html` in this new view and in this new view (modalOfDonations.html), I want to do an ng-repeat by the array of donations.

I want to keep the same controller of `user.html` too

does anybody can help? I am really a beginner in angular

**route**

```
.when("/modalOfDonations", {
    templateUrl: "modalOfDonations.html",
});
```

**user.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="ev in event">
    <article>{{ev.description}}</article>
    <a href="#!/modalOfDonations">
        <button>How can i help?</button>
    </a>
    <div ng-include src="'modalOfDonations.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**modalOfDonations.html**

```
<h4>Como posso contribuir?</h4>
<div ng-repeat="donations in ev.donateTypes">
    <div>{{donations.name}}</div>
    <div>{{donations.min}}</div>
    <div>{{donations.total}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is ev.donateTypes related to the ev in "ng-repeat='ev in event'" ?
Because if it is, you can not acces to it outside the ng-repeat.

Comment: but if i want to access from outside, how should i do? it's not possible?

Comment: is it possible to put the modal in the same html? so you can use ev.donateTypes. if not, then I think you need to make a controller for modal and pass the data to modal's controller like making Angular service module (but I don't think it's a good practice for just modal)

Comment: No you can not access it. Yeah I agree with AimeTPGM, a service shoud do the trick.

Comment: how about making a directive?

Comment: You should pass something like Id into `href="#!/modalOfDonations/{{ev.Id}}"` and correct routing to `.when("/modalOfDonations/:Id"`

Comment: @AimeTPGM i am not so familiar with them, i will have a look, tx